# Different package when app is getting launched (Lollipop or above issue)

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, package-name

From a background service, I am getting a launcher app package name.

Code used:

```
private String printForegroundTask() {
        String currentApp = "NULL";
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            UsageStatsManager usm = (UsageStatsManager) this.getSystemService(Context.USAGE_STATS_SERVICE);
            long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
            List<UsageStats> appList = usm.queryUsageStats(UsageStatsManager.INTERVAL_YEARLY, time - 1000 * 1000,
                    time);
            if (appList != null && appList.size() > 0) {
                SortedMap<Long, UsageStats> mySortedMap = new TreeMap<Long, UsageStats>();
                for (UsageStats usageStats : appList) {
                    mySortedMap.put(usageStats.getLastTimeUsed(), usageStats);
                }
                if (mySortedMap != null && !mySortedMap.isEmpty()) {
                    currentApp = mySortedMap.get(mySortedMap.lastKey()).getPackageName();
                }
            }
        } else {
            ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) this.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
            currentApp = am.getRunningTasks(1).get(0).topActivity.getPackageName();
        }
        return currentApp;
    }
```

When I launched the Downloads app, I am getting package name *com.android.documentsui*, but this package belong to Documents app.

Documents App: *com.android.documentsui*

Download Manager App: *com.android.providers.downloads*

Downloads App: *com.android.providers.downloads.ui*

I am facing this issue for Lollipop.

I checked the [App lock application](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.domobile.applock). I found that if Downloads app is locked and launched I see the Documents as the app name instead of Downloads,
i.e. app lock application is recognizing that all above defined packages belongs to same app.

[image]

Any idea regarding this?

Answer (score -1):

use this code so that you can get the package name of list of apps installed in moblie

final PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
//get a list of installed apps.
List packages = pm.getInstalledApplications(PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);

for (ApplicationInfo packageInfo : packages) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Installed package :" + packageInfo.packageName);
    Log.d(TAG, "Launch Activity :" + pm.getLaunchIntentForPackage(packageInfo.packageName)); 
}

Comment: Thanks for your effort. I think you didn't get my question. I want to get package name of any launched app from my service. I am getting package names but download app package name is not correct.

Comment: please read the question carefully. I dont want to print the list of installed app. I want to get the launched app package name. And I know these how to get. Actual problem is that package name of "Downlaod" app is not correct while getting this as launched app.